# Pytorch - View/Flatten (4, 10, 3, 368, 368) to (40, 3, 368, 368)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

How does one convert a tensor of shape  (4, 10, 3, 368, 368) to (40, 3, 368, 368). I am not able to find any documentation on this. I could hand code it but I'm sure there is any easier way to flatten the first two indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to reshape your 5D tensor to a 4D:

```
# some sample tensor to work with
In [12]: shape = (4, 10, 3, 368, 368)
In [13]: tensor_5D = torch.randn(shape)

In [14]: tensor_5D.shape
Out[14]: torch.Size([4, 10, 3, 368, 368])
```

Now, we will reshape the above tensor by flattening out the first two dimensions using the `view()` method:

```
In [22]: tensor_4D = tensor_5D.view(tuple((-1, *shape[2:])))

# desired shape
In [23]: tensor_4D.shape
Out[23]: torch.Size([40, 3, 368, 368])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions in PyTorch that can help you.

1. [view()](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view): Returns a new tensor with the same data as the self tensor but of a different size.
2. [reshape()](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html?highlight=reshape#torch.reshape): Returns a tensor with the same data and number of elements as input, but with the specified shape. *When possible, the returned tensor will be a view of input. Otherwise, it will be a copy.*

So, both of the following should work.

```
# input_tensor = (4, 10, 3, 368, 368)
output_tensor = input_tensor.view((-1, *input_tensor.shape[2:])) # option1
output_tensor = input_tensor.reshape((-1, *input_tensor.shape[2:])) # option2
```